# How to get states from a Vuex store from within a Vuetify list, VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

I have a Vue file that looks like so :

```
import store from '@/store'
export default{
    name: 'myList',
    data: () => ({
        show: true,
        listContent: [{
                name: '1',
                icon: 'person',
                value: function () {
                    return store.state.myStore.settings.one
                }
            }, {
                name: '2',
                icon: 'person',
                value: function () {
                    return store.state.myStore.settings.two
                }
            }, {
                name: '3',
                icon: 'person',
                value: function () {
                    return store.state.myStore.settings.three
                }
            }
        ]
    })
}
```

The part that's not working is getting the 'value' from the 'listContent'.

```
 {
    name: '3',
    icon: 'person',
    value: function () {
        return store.state.myStore.settings.three
    }
 }
```

In my code, I have imported the view as if I were to put :

```
this.$store.state.myStore.settings.one
```

Inside the value function, 'this' would refer to the object

```
{
    name: '3',
    icon: 'person',
    value: function () {
        return store.state.myStore.settings.three
    }
}
```

And I wouldnt be able to get the store. However, my code still doesn't work. I need to get access to the store inside the listContent.

The list is rendered like so :

```
<v-data-table :items="listContent" hide-actions hide-headers>
    <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">    
        <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right" v-text="props.item.value()">  </td>
    </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Either I have referenced the store incorrectly, or the template is incorrect. Any ideas ?

Comment: the store contains modules, and the module I want to get from is names 'myStore'

Comment: do you want those values to be reactive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want the `value` to be a function that returns the state value. You can just assign it to `state` value using `this.$store.state.myStore.settings.one`

For this to work make the `data` option a normal function instead of an arrow function so that `this` still represents the vue instance

```
export default {
  name: "myList",
  data() {
    return {
      show: true,
      listContent: [
        {
          name: "1",
          icon: "person",
          value: this.$store.state.myStore.settings.one
        },
        {
          name: "2",
          icon: "person",
          value: this.$store.state.myStore.settings.two
        },
        {
          name: "3",
          icon: "person",
          value: this.$store.state.myStore.settings.three
        }
      ]
    };
  }
};
```

Comment: @thatOneGuy it does work. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bfuhz1m4/2/). Have you registered the modules as an array or an object?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna see log, it's undefined

Comment: @AnkitKumarOjha that was just a test. forgot to remove. but see the output

Comment: i see yours works, i register as an object, ill debug mine

Comment: @VamsiKrishna i got it working. previously i had 'data: () => ({' and changed it to what you have : 'data() {  return {' and it works. Do you know the difference ?

Comment: for arrow functions, this is contextual.

Comment: @thatOneGuy i have mentioned in my answer. arrow functions bind the `this` lexically.  Vue has taken care to bind `this` to the vue instance, so use a normal function. Not only for `data` but also for `methods`, `computed`, `watchers`

Comment: @VamsiKrishna I'm struggling with committing a mutation from within a list, perhaps you could help ? I have asked another question, although these two are very similar, they are different https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51327747/how-to-commit-mutations-in-a-vuex-store-from-a-vuetify-list-vuejs

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help. Long one, but it works.

```
const myModule = {
  state: {
    test: "modulle",
    settings: {
      one: "This is one",
      two: "This is two",
      three: "This is three"
    }
  }
};

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: { myModule }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  store,
  data() {
    return {
      listContent: [
        {
          name: "1",
          icon: "person",
          value: null
        },
        {
          name: "2",
          icon: "person",
          value: null
        },
        {
          name: "3",
          icon: "person",
          value: null
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  watch:{
    '$store.state.myModule.settings.one':{
        immediate:true,
      handler:function(value){
            this.listContent[0].value = value;
      }
    },
    '$store.state.myModule.settings.two':{
        immediate:true,
      handler:function(value){
            this.listContent[1].value = value;
      }
    },
    '$store.state.myModule.settings.three':{
        immediate:true,
      handler:function(value){
            this.listContent[2].value = value;
      }
    },
  }
});
```

Comment: Setting up a watcher is redundant