# How to commit mutations in a Vuex store, from a Vuetify list, VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

This follows on from my previous question : [How to get states from a Vuex store from within a Vuetify list, VueJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51322760/how-to-get-states-from-a-vuex-store-from-within-a-vuetify-list-vuejs/51323061?noredirect=1#comment89623058_51323061)

I understand how to get states from the store, but I am struggling commiting mutations from within a list.

Here is my list :

```
export default{
    name: 'menuList',
    data() {
        return {
            show: true,
            items: [{
                    title: 'Do something',
                    icon: 'web',
                    event: function () {
                        this.$store.commit('UI/DoSomething', {
                            argument1: "argument1",
                            rootStore: this.$store
                        })
                    }

                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I have to have the event in a function as, if I don't, the commit will run straight away. I only want it to run when I click the button.

Here is my list creation :

```
<template>
  <v-navigation-drawer v-model="show" right clipped app fixed hide-overlay permanent="true">
    <v-list two-line>
      <template v-for="(item, index) in items">
        <v-list-tile :key="item.title" @click="item.event()">
          <v-list-tile-action>
            <v-icon>{{item.icon}}</v-icon>
          </v-list-tile-action>
          <v-list-tile-content>
            <v-list-tile-title v-html="item.title"></v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile-content>
        </v-list-tile>
        <v-divider :key="index"></v-divider>
      </template>
    </v-list>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>
```

When I wrap the commit with a function (so it doesn't execute automatically), the keyword 'this' refers to the object, not the Vue.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here, any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to store a function to commit a mutation in the `data` option?You can just store the information needed to commit a mutation.

```
export default{
    name: 'menuList',
    data() {
        return {
            show: true,
            items: [{
                    title: 'Do something',
                    icon: 'web',
                    mutation: {
                        type: 'UI/DoSomething',
                         arguments:{ 
                            argument1: "argument1",
                            rootStore: this.$store
                        }
                        }
                    }

                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Then create a method as follows

```
commitMutation(mutation) {
     this.$store.commit(mutation.type, mutation.arguments)

}
```

Then add a click listener with `item.mutation` as an argument to `commitMutation` method.

```
@click="commitMutation(itrm.mutation)"
```

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. Still getting my head around the way of working in Vue/Vuex, this helps a lot, thanks